# How to emit only one hair particle from each vertex?

Tags: particles, hair

How to emit only one hair particle from each vertex on mesh?

Can't believe such simple thing isn't implemented.

Comment: I don't think theres a way in vanilla blender. Usually the number of vertex of a given mesh is fixed. Can you make an example of usage?

Comment: @Carlo for example I want to make tiled roof. The idea is to create simple roof plane and emit from each vertex a roof tile, so you can create all kinds of tile variations and control how many tiles you want by controling vertecies on plane.

Comment: Why do you think it is not implemented? BTW another option is "instancing". Parent "tile" to "roof plane" and under "Object Properties" > "Instancing" enable "Verts".

Answer (score 6):

You absolutely can.

Make particles come from verts, uncheck "random order" and input on the "number" the exact number of vertexes you object has.
[image]8 in the case of a cube.

Crazy shape? No problem!

[image]

Just match verts and number of hairs.

Wanna use a collection of objects? No problem!
Just make sure the origins are all consistent. [image]

Comment: But with using an object collection instead of path?

Comment: CORRECTION: it works just fine even with collections, I just screwed the locations of the instanced objects.